# SSRS Custom colour of line chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts

I created a copy of my fully functioning report which contains line charts.
I created  custom code in the Report- Report Properties- Code.

When you click the lines in the chart itself in it's Properties I reference the code as  =Code.Getcolor(Fields!NameID.Value).

There has been no change. It works in the previous report but not the new one. I have tried to delete the code and re-paste, it did not make any difference. The colours are still the default.

Hope this makes sense. Please can someone help as I need to complete the testing by tomorrow.

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve this. In my Report code I was referencing slightly different Subcodes. Instead of A1 I used GradeA1.  Very slight change made it work
Previous- Case "Grade A1"
Now-      Case "A1"